Fail to setup:upgrade and setup:di:compile after upgrading to 2.4.7 and 2.4.7-p3 - Failed to open Stream
I've tried everything from upgrading all modules, give right permissions, removing generated folder, dumping composer, nothing works and I can't setup:upgrade or setup:di:compile.
Please help, thanks in advance
php bin/magento setup:upgrade Cache types config flushed successfully Cache cleared successfully File system cleanup: /home/£££/public_html/generated/code/Amasty /home/£££/public_html/generated/code/Aws /home/£££/public_html/generated/code/Codazon /home/£££/public_html/generated/code/Composer /home/£££/public_html/generated/code/Magento /home/£££/public_html/generated/code/PayPal /home/£££/public_html/generated/code/Psr /home/£££/public_html/generated/code/StripeIntegration /home/£££/public_html/generated/code/Symfony The directory '/home/£££/public_html/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup Updating modules: Warning: include(/home/£££/public_html/vendor/composer/../../generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/£££/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 576

 php bin/magento setup:di:compile Warning: include(/home/£££/public_html/vendor/composer/../../generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/Proxy.php): Failed toopen stream: No such file or directory in /home/£££/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 576

somewhere it is suggested to update composer. It gives me many warnings, is it normal or I have to fix them all? Hints to do it?
>     [£££@srv2 public_html]$ composer update
>     Loading composer repositories with package information
>     Updating dependencies
>     Nothing to modify in lock file
>     Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
>     Nothing to install, update or remove
>     Package laminas/laminas-crypt is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
>     Package laminas/laminas-mail is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
>     Generating optimized autoload files
>     Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl" was found in both
> "/home/£££/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php"
> and
> "/home/£££/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php",
> the first will be used.
>     Class Codazon\ThemeLayoutPro\Block\Adminhtml\Footer\Edit\Button\Generic
> located in
> ./app/code/Codazon/ThemeLayoutPro/Controller/Adminhtml/MainContent/Generic.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Edit\Button\Back located in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Block/Adminhtml/Index/Edit/Button/Back.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Edit\Button\Delete located in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Block/Adminhtml/Index/Edit/Button/Delete.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Edit\Button\Generic located
> in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Block/Adminhtml/Index/Edit/Button/Generic.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Edit\Button\Reset located in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Block/Adminhtml/Index/Edit/Button/Reset.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Edit\Button\Save located in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Block/Adminhtml/Index/Edit/Button/Save.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Console\Resize located in ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Console/Resize.php does not comply
> with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Console\Synchronize located in ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Console/Synchronize.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Delete located in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Delete.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index located in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete located in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/MassDelete.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassStatus located in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/MassStatus.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\ResizeProductImage
> located in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/ResizeProductImage.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\ResizeSelectedImage
> located in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/ResizeSelectedImage.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save located in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Save.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Update located in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Update.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Dolphin\ResizeImage\Model\ResourceModel\Resizeimage\Grid\Collection
> located in
> ./app/code/Dolphin/ResizeImagebk/Model/ResourceModel/Resizeimage/Grid/Collection.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Block\SocialShare located in ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Block/SocialShare.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Helper\Data located in ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Helper/Data.php does not comply
> with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Model\System\Config\Source\BackgroundColor
> located in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Model/System/Config/Source/BackgroundColor.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Model\System\Config\Source\ButtonColor located in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Model/System/Config/Source/ButtonColor.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Model\System\Config\Source\ButtonSize located in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Model/System/Config/Source/ButtonSize.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Model\System\Config\Source\DisplayMenu located in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Model/System/Config/Source/DisplayMenu.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Model\System\Config\Source\FloatApplyFor located
> in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Model/System/Config/Source/FloatApplyFor.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Model\System\Config\Source\FloatCmsPages located
> in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Model/System/Config/Source/FloatCmsPages.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Model\System\Config\Source\FloatPosition located
> in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Model/System/Config/Source/FloatPosition.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Model\System\Config\Source\FloatSelectPages
> located in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Model/System/Config/Source/FloatSelectPages.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Model\System\Config\Source\IconColor located in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Model/System/Config/Source/IconColor.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Model\System\Config\Source\InlineApplyFor
> located in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Model/System/Config/Source/InlineApplyFor.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Model\System\Config\Source\InlinePosition
> located in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Model/System/Config/Source/InlinePosition.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Model\System\Config\Source\OptionArray located in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Model/System/Config/Source/OptionArray.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\SocialShare\Model\System\Config\Source\Style located in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/SocialShare/Model/System/Config/Source/Style.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\TwitterWidget\Block\Adminhtml\System\Snippet located in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/TwitterWidget/Block/Adminhtml/System/Snippet.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\TwitterWidget\Block\Widget located in ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/TwitterWidget/Block/Widget.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\TwitterWidget\Controller\Twitter\Index located in ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/TwitterWidget/Controller/Twitter/Index.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\TwitterWidget\Helper\Data located in ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/TwitterWidget/Helper/Data.php does not comply
> with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\TwitterWidget\Model\Config\Source\Chrome located in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/TwitterWidget/Model/Config/Source/Chrome.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\TwitterWidget\Model\Config\Source\Design located in
> ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/TwitterWidget/Model/Config/Source/Design.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\TwitterWidget\Model\Config\Source\Theme located in ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/TwitterWidget/Model/Config/Source/Theme.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mageplaza\TwitterWidget\Model\Config\Source\Type located in ./app/code/Mbs/Mageplaza/TwitterWidget/Model/Config/Source/Type.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Mbs\Title\Plugin\ProductTitleWithBrand located in ./app/code/Mbs/mbstitle/Plugin/ProductTitleWithBrand.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class BaseIgfsCgInit located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/init/BaseIgfsCgInit.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IgfsCgInit located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/init/IgfsCgCheckout.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IgfsCgInit located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/init/IgfsCgInit.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IgfsCgSelector located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/init/IgfsCgSelector.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IgfsCgVerify located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/init/IgfsCgVerify.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class TerminalInfo located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/init/TerminalInfo.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class BaseIgfsCgMpi located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/mpi/BaseIgfsCgMpi.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IgfsCgMpiAuth located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/mpi/IgfsCgMpiAuth.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IgfsCgMpiEnroll located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/mpi/IgfsCgMpiEnroll.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class BaseIgfsCgTran located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/tran/BaseIgfsCgTran.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IgfsCgAuth located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/tran/IgfsCgAuth.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IgfsCgConfirm located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/tran/IgfsCgConfirm.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IgfsCgCredit located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/tran/IgfsCgCredit.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IgfsCgVoidAuth located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/tran/IgfsCgVoidAuth.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class BaseIgfsCg located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/BaseIgfsCg.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IgfsException located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/Exception.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IgfsMissingParException located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/Exception.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IOException located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/Exception.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class ConnectionException located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/Exception.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard.Skipping.
>     Class ReadWriteException located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/Exception.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class IgfsUtils located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/IgfsUtils.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Level3Info located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/Level3Info.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Level3InfoProduct located in ./app/code/QeeWeb/Pagonline/lib/IGFS_CG_API/Level3InfoProduct.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class Sm\TwitterSlider\Model\Config\Source\Effect located in ./app/code/Sm/InstagramGallery/Model/Config/Source/Effect.php does not
> comply withpsr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer\RewriteStatus located
> in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Renderer/RewriteStatus.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Disable
> located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/Disable.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\EmptyField
> located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/EmptyField.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Extensions located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Extensions.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Notification located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Notification.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\SystemInformation
> located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/SystemInformation.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Block\Adminhtml\Debugger located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Block/Adminhtml/Debugger.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Block\Adminhtml\Licenses located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Block/Adminhtml/Licenses.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Block\Adminhtml\ModulesVersion located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Block/Adminhtml/ModulesVersion.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Debugger\Modules located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Controller/Adminhtml/Debugger/Modules.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Debugger\Rewrites located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Controller/Adminhtml/Debugger/Rewrites.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Debugger\Rewritesall located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Controller/Adminhtml/Debugger/Rewritesall.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Debugger\Rewritescustom located
> in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Controller/Adminhtml/Debugger/Rewritescustom.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Licenses\Index located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Controller/Adminhtml/Licenses/Index.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Licenses\Post located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Controller/Adminhtml/Licenses/Post.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Debugger located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Controller/Adminhtml/Debugger.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Licenses located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Controller/Adminhtml/Licenses.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Cron\ModuleInfoUpdate located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Cron/ModuleInfoUpdate.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Helper\Developer located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Helper/Developer.php does not comply
> with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Helper\License located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Helper/License.php does not comply with
> psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Helper\Utility located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Helper/Utility.php does not comply with
> psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Model\Config\Source\Yesno located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Model/Config/Source/Yesno.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Model\ResourceModel\Debugger\Grid\Collection located
> in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Model/ResourceModel/Debugger/Grid/Collection.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Model\ResourceModel\License\Collection located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Model/ResourceModel/License/Collection.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Model\ResourceModel\License located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Model/ResourceModel/License.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Model\Feed located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Model/Feed.php does not comply with
> psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Model\License located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Model/License.php does not comply with
> psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Model\Logger located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Model/Logger.php does not comply with
> psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Model\Scanner located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Model/Scanner.php does not comply with
> psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Observer\AdminLoginSuccessObserver located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Observer/AdminLoginSuccessObserver.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Observer\PredispatchAdminActionControllerObserver
> located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Observer/PredispatchAdminActionControllerObserver.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Category\DataProvider located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Plugin/Category/DataProvider.php does
> not complywith psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Logger located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Plugin/Logger.php does not comply with
> psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Utility located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Plugin/Utility.php does not comply with
> psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Setup\UpgradeData located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Setup/UpgradeData.php does not comply
> with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\Backend\Setup\UpgradeSchema located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/Backendbk/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php does not comply
> with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Block\Breadcrumbs located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Block/Breadcrumbs.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Block\FacebookOpenGraph located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Block/FacebookOpenGraph.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Block\GoogleCards located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Block/GoogleCards.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Block\RichSnippet located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Block/RichSnippet.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Block\TwitterCards located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Block/TwitterCards.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Helper\Data located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Helper/Data.php does not comply
> with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Model\Config\Backend\Image located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Model/Config/Backend/Image.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Model\Config\Source\Brand located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Model/Config/Source/Brand.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Model\Config\Source\CardType located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Model/Config/Source/CardType.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Model\Config\Source\ContactOption located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Model/Config/Source/ContactOption.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Model\Config\Source\ContactType located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Model/Config/Source/ContactType.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
    >     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Model\Config\Source\Price located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Model/Config/Source/Price.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Model\Config\Source\Reviews located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Model/Config/Source/Reviews.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Model\Pricing\Render\Amount located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Model/Pricing/Render/Amount.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Model\BreadcrumbStorage located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Model/BreadcrumbStorage.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Observer\AddUpdateHandlesObserver located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Observer/AddUpdateHandlesObserver.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Plugin\BreadcrumbsPlugin located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Plugin/BreadcrumbsPlugin.php does
> not complywith psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Plugin\ReviewRendererPlugin located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Plugin/ReviewRendererPlugin.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Plugin\Utility located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Plugin/Utility.php does not comply
> with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\GoogleCards\Setup\UpgradeData located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleCardsbk/Setup/UpgradeData.php does not
> comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\LazyLoading\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\LazyLoadingCompatibilityNotice
> located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/LazyLoadingbk/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/LazyLoadingCompatibilityNotice.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\LazyLoading\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\LazyLoadingTutorial
> located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/LazyLoadingbk/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/LazyLoadingTutorial.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\LazyLoading\Block\Product\ImageFactory located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/LazyLoadingbk/Block/Product/ImageFactory.php does
> not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\LazyLoading\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Disable located in
> ./app/code/WeltPixel/LazyLoadingbk/Block/System/Config/Form/Field/Disable.php
> does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\LazyLoading\Helper\Data located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/LazyLoadingbk/Helper/Data.php does not comply
> with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     Class WeltPixel\LazyLoading\Plugin\Utility located in ./app/code/WeltPixel/LazyLoadingbk/Plugin/Utility.php does not comply
> with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping.
>     128 packages you are using are looking for funding.
>     Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
>     No security vulnerability advisories found.
>     [£££@srv2 public_html]$ ^C
>     [£££@srv2 public_html]$


not sure of what is the fix but  hired a freelancer and he told me he chenged composer.json and I updated theme module

it resulted in some cache composer, we forced update installing modules without caching and solving problems
